# Undo all of the changes & delete new files while not being on any branch (being on an older tag)

Tags: git

I checked out an older tag to investigate some issues by `git checkout ....`, then did some changes to investigate more, then I checked out the master.

The problem is while I was in the older tag, I did some changes which I wanted to discard before returning to the last tag, but I couldn't (as I was on on rhe lder tag `git status showed me not currently on any branch`.

I used `git clead -fd` and `git reset --hard`, but none of them worked. I also didn't want to `stash` them. I wanted complete undoing of changes.

I ended up to manually undo the chages file by file, but there should be a better way.

In addition, I could `git checkout master` without undoing of changes, but out of curiosity I want to know if there is a better way.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` followed by `git clean -fdx` should return your working directory to exactly `HEAD` and nothing else, regardless of whether you're on a branch or not, unless you have some line ending conversion issues or some odd smudge/clean filters...

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask why you do not want to use `git stash`? It is exactly why it exist.
Maybe you do not know that there are options `git stash apply` and `git stash pop` using which you can control what is on the stash (stack).

Comment: I don't want to stash anything. I did some changes for investigation and now I want to get rid of all the changes, there should be a way like `git reset --hard`, but as I am not on any branch, it doesn't work.